# How to display the corrected field in a form in Django?

Tags: django, forms

Let's say I have a Person model which has for example 2 attributes : a name and some job experiences (a textarea).

I have a form to create a Person and I have created a custom validation rule for the TextField (the job experiences).

I would like to display the errors associated to the TextField (the job experiences) (I have already done that.
And I would like to display the content of the TextField but corrected : I just don't know how to display it.

For example, here are some job experiences entered by the user :

```
Work at McDonalds for 2 years, Study Customer Service for 1 year
```

When the user submit the form, this would be invalid because of my custom validation rule for the TextField.
**I just would like to display the corrected input in the form page (not in the TextField but just below as a paragraph for example), ** just to give the user a way to see his corrected input :

```
- Work at McDonalds for 2 years
- Study Customer Service for 1 year
```

I have tried this to display the corrected input in the form page  :

```
class PersonCreate(CreateView):
  model = Person
  form_class = PersonForm
  success_url = 'my_site/success.html'
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # I have an error with the following line : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'job_experiences'
    job_experiences = self.object.job_experiences
    #here is my code to get the formatted text
    formatted_job_experiences = my_code(job_experiences)
    context = super(PersonCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['formatted_job_experiences'] = formatted_job_experiences
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no instance when creating the object, the form field values are in the `data` dict. Try this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # on initial GET data will be empty, thus the default value 
    job_experiences = kwargs['form'].data.get('job_experiences', '')
    return super(PersonCreate, self).get_context_data(
        formatted_job_experiences=my_code(job_experiences),
        **kwargs
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have the following error now : KeyError at /my_site/person/add/  'form'

Comment: The base implementations in `CreateView` always call `get_context_data` with `form=form`, have you overridden this in any way that isn't shown in the question?